# Direct2D: Check if image is outside visible area before drawing?

Tags: direct2d

Is it a reasonable optimization to omit calls to ID2D1HwndRenderTarget::DrawBitmap() if the image will end up outside the visible area? If I implement the checking logic in the application that will cost some performance, so if the first thing D2D does is doing the same check then I'd rather not do it.

Comment: You can try both ways and see if there is any measurable difference. I'd expect that such intersection tests are already happening.

Comment: Most of this (clipping, etc.) should be coded in drivers now (like for ~20 years): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/guard-band-clipping but it also depends on the details of your code. By default I would trust D2D.

Answer (score 0):

I had a test with my application which renders some UI part using Direct2D (and attaching renderdoc), seems it is a bit random.

I render a mix of Rectangles, Text, Path geometries (beziers) and Rectangle with a bitmap brush (which should be equivalent to your DrawBitmap call).

Then I capture a frame with all those objects visible, and another one panning my UI (using transform) so objects are not visible.

From there could check what is drawn or not:

- Text is always culled
- Solid color rectangles are not culled
- Most of the times path geometries are culled, but sometimes not.
- Rectangle with bitmap brush are NEVER culled

So it seems Direct2D is making different decisions depending on the types of elements you plan to draw.

Since rectangles are easily batched and cheap to draw, it seems that they are just drawn regardless.

Bitmap rectangles and text require more work, so it seems they are effectively culled.

Path geometry was looking to depend on how many polygon the geometry is tesselated to (I had a path that was translating to 26 primitives and it was not culled, another one translating to 120 and it got culled).

So you can either trust Direct2D that it will perform that optimization, but I would personally implement a quick rectangle to rectangle check just in case (it's not gonna hurt your performances as its an extremely simple operation).